# Velocitiy of the mass on the moveable spring system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, momentum, energy-conservation

[image: Main question]

Actually I am confused at the this question. Generally kinetic energy is not conservative at momentum questions if there is no elastic collision but there is no friction on the system too.

Should I use energy conservation on the spring or not? Could you explain when should I use energy equality?

Comment: Is there anywhere for the energy in the spring to go other than to the velocities of each mass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no friction and no inelastic collision so, yes, energy is conserved. The energy of the compressed spring is $\frac 1 2 kd^2$ so conservation of energy gives you:

$\frac 1 2 mv_m^2 + \frac 1 2 Mv_p^2 = \frac 1 2 kd^2$

and conservation of momentum gives you:

$mv_m + Mv_p = 0$

Comment: I understood that but i can't see how to solve this 2 equations for the answer. Do you have any idea to solve it?

Comment: @WLA From the second equation you can get $v_p = \frac{-mv_m}{M}$. Then substitute for $v_p$ in the first equation and re-arrange to get an expression for $v_m$ in terms of $k,d,M$ and $m$.